# JMeter ignores path

Tags: node.js, performance, jmeter, performance-testing

I m actually trying to use JMeter to make some perf tests and I m having some troubles.

Actually, I have an api running on port 3333 on localhost (same machine as the JMeter tool) that has a "project" ressource.

Actually, we can access the "project" ressources of a user send him a request like :

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:3333/v1/projects?access_token=SUPER_TOKEN
```

Here are Request Defaults configurations :

[image]

And here's my request configuration :

[image]

When I try to start my test, the request is well sent and I m having a response from my server. (I can log it inside of my nodejs server)

The fact is that JMeter only get on the following ressource :

```
GET /?access_token=104c7420-d6ec-11e5-9eb2-036723e1d0d2
```

Which is not what I m telling him.

I m pretty sure I m doing something bad.

Can anybody help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You can not use the HTTP Request Defaults's **Path** field to add a prefix to the HTTP Request Path.

Check [JMeter - HTTP Request Defaults](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults)

`the path is the default for the full path, not a prefix to be applied to paths specified on the HTTP Request screens.`

So, Remove the `/v1` from the HTTP request defaults and update the correct path for the HTTP requests.

HTTP Requests - Path should be `/v1/projects`